# How to select only non-zero values from multiple table conditional sum query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am having a tough time to eliminate the rows having zero values in particular expression, any help here highly appericiated

Here are my two simple tables

```
create table tbl1
(id int, account varchar(50), stock varchar(50), price int, vol int);

insert into tbl1 values
(1, 'a1', 's1', 10, 5),
(2, 'a1', 's2', 5, 5),
(3, 'a2', 's1', 15, 3),
(4, 'a2', 's2', 20, 2),
(5, 'a2', 's2', 20, 2);

create table tbl2
(id int, tid int, price int, vol int);

insert into tbl2 values
(1, 1, 5, 3),
(2, 1, 5, 1),
(3, 1, 15, 1),
(4, 2, 5, 3),
(5, 2, 6, 2);
```

My select is as follows, it gives me what I need but it also gives me the rows where 
`(t1.vol - ifnull(Sum(t2.vol), 0))` returns zero

```
select 
t1.id,account,stock,
(t1.vol - ifnull(Sum(t2.vol), 0)) vol
from tbl1 t1 
left join tbl2 t2 on t1.id=t2.tid
group by t1.id
```

Could somebody help me in getting rid of these zero values?

I tried `having (t1.vol - ifnull(Sum(t2.vol), 0)) <> 0` ==> it says vol is invalid column 
I tried `where (t1.vol - ifnull(Sum(t2.vol), 0)) <> 0` ==> it says Invalid use of group function

here is the output I get now with the above query

```
ID  ACCOUNT STOCK   VOL
1   a1      s1      0
2   a1      s2      0
3   a2      s1      3
4   a2      s2      2
5   a2      s2      2
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
select 
t1.id,account,stock,
(t1.vol - ifnull(Sum(t2.vol), 0)) vol
from tbl1 t1 
left join tbl2 t2 on t1.id=t2.tid
group by t1.id
having vol <> 0
```

Comment: how simple the solution was... took my good amount of time to figure this out.. Adding `having vol <> 0` worked for me to eliminate zero value rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your query like below

```
select t1.id,
t1.account,
t1.stock,
(t1.vol - coalesce(tab.vol_total,0)) as vol
from tbl1 t1 
left join 
(
select tid,Sum(vol) as vol_total
from tbl2 
group by tid
) tab
on t1.id=tab.tid
where (t1.vol - coalesce(tab.vol_total,0)) > 0
```

Comment: this returns the same output what my query returns. Anyways thanks for the quick response

Comment: Does that mean, it giving wrong result? (OR) expected result?

Comment: with the updated query, VOL column has all NULL values

Comment: Ah!! my bad; I didn't used `COALESCE` while calculating `VOL`. Try the edited query. See this fiddle to prove that it works as expected http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f858c/29.